# If exists update else insert em tabela com chave estrangeira postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Preciso fazer um insert em uma tabela com chave estrangeira, então caso esse registro nao exista na outra tabela preciso de fazer um insert, consigo fazer essa operação utilizando o if exists? Alguma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `IF EXISTS`, verificando se o valor existe na tabela com a FK:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TabelaFK WHERE campo = valor) THEN
  -- insere os dados na tabela "FK"
END IF;
```

Referência (em inglês) do `PostgreSQL`: [EXIST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)

Também pode ser feito assim:

```
declare 
tot integer;

SELECT count(*) INTO tot
FROM forma_pagamento WHERE descricao like '%dinheiro%'

IF tot> 0 THEN
   insert into forma_pagamento (id_conta_preferencial, id_operadora_cartao, descricao, ativo, caixa, conta, cartao, cheque_proprio, cheque_terceiro) values (2, 2, 'dinheiro', true, false, false, false, false, false)
END IF;
```

Comment: No postgres parece que nao funciona essa sintaxe, olha minha sql que esta apresentando erro:

if not exists (
select id
 from forma_pagamento
    where descricao like '%dinheiro%') then
    insert into forma_pagamento (id_conta_preferencial, id_operadora_cartao, descricao, ativo, caixa, conta, cartao, cheque_proprio, cheque_terceiro)
 values (2, 2, 'dinheiro', true, false, false, false, false, false)
    end if

Comment: Você está usando `like` para comparar? E se trouxer mais de um registro, de qual vai pegar o ID? Tente limitar o resultado adicionando no final do seu `select` isso: `LIMIT 1`

Comment: adicionei outra solução que pode resolver caso o `limit` não funcione

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 1: declare tot integer;

Comment: Parece estar faltando um `BEGIN` antes do `SELECT` e um `END` no final, após o `END IF;`. Falta um ponto-e-vírgula também no final das querys.